# intersection and cartesian product

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $  \mathbb{N}\supseteq A, B $.

$|B \times A| = 35,$ and $|A\times B \setminus B\times B| = 14$.

Find $|A \cap B|$.

I figured out that $|B|$ must be 5 and $|A|$ must be 7, but that I got stuck.

Comment: hint:$$|A\times B \setminus B\times B| = 14\\
|A\times B - B\times B| = 14\\
|(A-B)\times B| = 14$$

Comment: The hint justifies my assumption about the groups' size, but how can I figure out the intersection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the hint, we have $$|A\times B| = 35 \qquad |(A\setminus B) \times B|=14$$Using that $|A\times B|=|A|\cdot |B|$, and the previous equations, we conclude that $|B|$ has to divide both $14$ and $35$.

Now, note that $|A\setminus B|= |A|-|A\cap B|$.

Comment: The last line is what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$|A\times B \setminus B\times B| = 14\\
|A\times B - B\times B| = 14\\
|(A-B)\times B| = 14$$
$$|A\times B - B\times B|=|A\times B -(A\times B)\cap (B\times B)|= \\
|A\times B -(A\cap B)\times B)|=\\
|A\times B |-|(A\cap B)\times B)|=14\\\to 35-|(A\cap B)\times B)|=14\\|(A\cap B)\times B)|=21=3\times7$$note that $A \cap B \subset B \to |A \cap B|\leq |B| \to |A\cap B|=3,|B|=7$